# xslt output character "&#8232;"

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In one of my use cases, my XSLT 2.0 transformation (powered by Saxon and JAVA)  generates extra `&#8232;` character in my output wherever space or newline character is encountered.

However, when the same transformation is done using XSLT 1.0 ( powered by libXSLT and Perl) it does not get this particular character in the output.

I have already referred to this [query](https://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/13252370/) which explains that SAXON essentially serializes these special characters for round-trips.

My question is, why is the behavior different in case of XSLT 1.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose XSLT 1.0 from 1999 is older than XML 1.1 which requires the normalization of that character in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends whereas XML 1.0 https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends does not cover that character. XSLT 2.0's serialization rules as outlined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xml-output do take XML 1.1 into account, XSLT 1.0 being older does not.

Comment: .....A quick follow up question. Where should I specify the `version 1.1` ? A] XSLT file header 2] `xslt:stylesheet version` or 3] in the place where output file is generated i.e `exsl:document version` so that I can get the character reference properly generated ?

Comment: I did not suggest to specify version 1.1, I only tried to speculate on the history of the development of the spec. I don't see what `exsl:document` has to do with that and Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0. You might want to ask a new question and elaborate or edit this one and provide details of input, XSLT, wanted result and current result.